# Are there accepted tools for performing mapping/modeling from flat files to JSON?

Tags: mapping, uml, data-modeling, modeling

We have a very complex JSON schema and have to ingest data from an external source.  The first step in being able to ingest that data is to be able to map the data elements we are ingesting to the JSON elements in our standard structure so that we know how to populate our JSON schema.  Are there standard methods or tools for doing this?  Here is an example...albeit, an extremely simple example.

Say we have an example schema that looks like:

```
{"name": "James",
 "address": [{"type":"Home", 
              "street": "123 Main",
              "city": "Anycity",
              "state": "CA"}]
 "age": 32}
```

And I have a flat file that looks something like:

```
NAME, ADDRESS_TYPE, STREET, CITY, STATE, AGE
Greg, Home, 456 Elm, Los Angeles, CA, 22
Mike, Work, 999 Main, San Diego, CA, 33
```

Given this is a fairly obvious example, but the data I am dealing with is very complex.  I need a way to represent the mapping of the column headers (e.g. NAME, ADDRESS_TYPE, etc) to the elements in the JSON schema and also be able to include  other information like logic that may be applied to the incoming data that determines where/how the data should be mapped into the schema.  I could do something like:

```
{"name": "<NAME>",
 "address": [{"type":"<ADDRESS_TYPE>", 
              "street": "<STREET>",
              "city": "<CITY>",
              "state": "<STATE>"}]
 "age": <AGE>}
```

But with this sort of template approach, I don't have a way to express logic...like, "...if the address_type is not in a pre-defined list of types, then use HOME by default"

I'm just wondering if there is a standard way for mapping/modeling source data elements to JSON?

Comment: There is no such standard, but you can easily model the above with a class and a couple of (OCL) constraints.

Comment: Your question is about modeling or tool ? If this is tool, we use swagger to define rest/wsdl interfaces, to generate java mapping file, and to create quickly stub/proxy and simulateur. Then we use jmeter to perform injection for testing. But this has nothing to do with modeling ...

Comment: I think I'm interested in both.  I'd like to know if (1) there is a best practices way of representing the data mapping, and (2) if there is a tool that can be used for representing the mapping and tracking changes.